# Using a loop with bootstrap to add multiple events

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, sass, bootstrap-modal

I'm designing a website which allows me to create announcements:[image: Picture of what the announcements would look like]

When I click on the plus sign, a window should appear to indicate more detail as demonstrated here:[image: In depth view of the announcement]

I am trying to loop through and add a javascript function to make the information from each announcement appear for each plus sign. However, I encounter a problem where each plus sign instead displays information from the first announcement (Test 2). My code is below:

```
<% @announcements.each do |announcement| %>
<!-- sets each announcement to be 3 per row -->
<div class="col-md-4 announcement-div">
    <!-- Title and subject of the announcement -->
    <p>
        <span class="topBottom"><%= announcement.subject %></span>
        <br>
        <%= announcement.created_at.strftime("%m/%d %Y %I:%M %p") %>
    </p>
    <!-- Stars to signify important events -->
    <% if announcement.importance %>
        <h2>&#9733;</h2>
    <% end %>
    <!-- The plus sign button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn popup-btn">+</button>
    <!-- Current announcement Display Code -->
    <div id="announcementDisplayModal" class="modal">
        <span id="announcementDisplayModal-close" class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('announcementDisplayModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
        <div class="modal-content well modal-dimensions">
            <h3 class="cardinal borders"> <%= announcement.subject %> </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And the javascript:

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('announcementDisplayModal');

$('.popup-btn').click(function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
});

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementById("announcementDisplayModal-close");

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Any ideas on how to fix? I tried changing it from getElementById to get element by class type and changing the ID to a class, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, one thing you need to notice is the ID of an element in a document must be unique. But in this case you are repeating `announcementDisplayModal`.

So to fix this problem instead of using an ID selector, try this,

instead of,

```
$('.popup-btn').click(function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
});
```

try,

```
$('.popup-btn').click(function() {
    $(this).next().css('display', 'block');
});
```

Comment: Hey @akhil.cs thanks for your help, this worked. Any advice on closing the popups? I have it situated so that I add an "x" button using bootstraps close class, but I can't figure out how to link the opening to closing.